# Docker Compose Link (Alias)

Tags: angularjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have an Angularjs frontend and a Spring-Boot Rest API in backend.
I have create two Docker

***DockerFile Front:***

```
FROM httpd:2.4
COPY ./public-html/ /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/
```

***DockerFile Back:***

```
FROM tomcat:8.0
EXPOSE 8080
COPY rest-api.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/rest-api.war
```

I have a Docker-Compose file, i have define Alias

***Docker-Compose:***

```
rest:
 image: restapi
 container_name: restapi
 ports:
  - "8080:8080"


frontend:
 image: frontend
 container_name: frontend
 ports:
  - "80:80"
```

[image]
 i redifine the `baseURL` in my AngularJs controller

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $http, MainService) {
    var that = this;
    var baseUrl = 'http://rest:8080';
```

when i lauchn my app in the console i have this

***Error:***

```
GET http://rest:8080/category net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
```

the hosts files in the other containers is not updated automatically
[image]
What is wrong ?

****** ***UPDATE*** ******

I have create a network

```
$docker network create my-network
```

I have redefine my docker-compose file

Container connected to that network reach other containers.

So i have the same error.

When i see in Kitematic my Backend have an ip like this:

[image]

And when i see in the hosts files the ip is not the same.

[image]

When i modify my controller with ip of Kitematic all works but when i use Alias is not working

Comment: add: `links: - rest` to your frontend docker-compose yml section

Comment: Dear gentlemen, if you downvote please give at least a small comment how my answer can be improved

Comment: I think it comes from that fact that you are asking about links and aliases while the actual problem comes from trying to access a Docker container's internal IP from outside of the Docker host. The question title is about links, the actual problem is about misunderstanding how Docker creates (virtual) networks.

Answer (score 5):

So you are trying to use the linked alias inside your browser (Angular)  application? Docker only exposes these aliases to the containers. Your local development system, being outside of the docker network, will not have these additions to the host file and therefore not be able to resolve hosts to IPs.

Any application running inside the containers, like a Node.js backend, will be able to use these aliases. Browsers can't.

Comment: Your browser will only ever be able to connect to the external IP address of your docker host (the one you get from running `docker-machine ip` in the Terminal) or something you added to your own `/etc/hosts` file manually. The internal IP of your individual containers won't be reachable from the outside, that is by design.

Comment: Just imagine this: if you were to start a browser INSIDE your Docker host virtual machine, you would be able to access the internal IPs and even host aliases. Since you are starting your browser OUTSIDE the Docker host, you can't access those.

Comment: I execute my angularjs Frontend into Docker A and my Backend into Docker B. When i launch my app i call ip of Docker A but Docker A don't show Docker B

Comment: Then using `docker-compose` and have the frontend container use `links` with the rest container like in the answer above is the only sensible way of connecting these two.

Comment: can you post an example

Answer (score 1):

You can try and link the two containers in the configuration file.

```
rest:
 image: restapi
 container_name: restapi
 ports:
  - "8080:8080"


frontend:
 image: frontend
 container_name: frontend
 ports:
  - "80:80"
 links:
  - rest
```

Comment: have you an example please ..?

Comment: `←[31mERROR←[0m: Circular import between frontend and rest`

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new network, any container connected to that network can reach other containers by their name or service name.

**create network**

```
$docker network create your-network
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
rest:
 image: restapi
 container_name: restapi
 ports:
  - "8080:8080"
 net: your-network  


frontend:
 image: frontend
 container_name: frontend
 ports:
 - "80:80"
 net: your-network
```

**Note** if you use docker-compose file version 2.0. composer will create the network for you.

Comment: how to know the versionof docker-compose file ?

Comment: Currently you are using Compose file format – version 1 (the legacy format, which does not support volumes or networks). See more info about the differences between version 1 and version 2 at : https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#versioning